# Cocoa/Cocoa-touch best practice for custom drawing of a UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, objective-c

I'm looking for insight on a best practice for the following:

I have a UITableView in which I'd like to draw a custom shape into each UITableViewCell. Something such as the "pill" shape ellipse in Apple's mail app that describes how many messages are in a folder.

What's the best practice for that? Should I subclass UIView, and add the class to my UITableView, then use drawAtPoint:?

I prefer not subclassing UITableViewCell, and I'm almost certain there isn't a need for it. My cells are rather common otherwise.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would design my cells in Interface Builder. I will be way easier than subclassing UITableViewCell class, and you will find an awesome video tutorial on how to do that [here](http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/182). And, without coding, you will have the opportunity to design your custom components with a very nice GUI tool.

For the ellipse-like drawing you can use a plain UIView subclass that you can place wherever you want with Interface Builder.